If $A^*A=A^*B=B^*A=B^*B$, prove that $A=B$.
Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $A,B\in B(H)$ are such that $A^*A=A^*B=B^*A=B^*B$,then $A=B$.I'm having difficulty trying to read a proof that solves this problem.
First, the author decomposes $H$ as $H=\overline{R(A^*)}\oplus null(A)$, then write $A$ as $A=\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0 \\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and write $B$ as $B=\begin{pmatrix}B_{11}&B_{12} \\\ B_{21}&B_{22}\end{pmatrix}$, where $A_1$ is claimed to have dense range. Then from the equation $A^*A=B^*B$ the author deduces that $B_{12}^*B_{12}+B_{22}^*B_{22}=0$ and then $B_{12}=B_{22}=0$.
My questions:
1)Why does the equation $A=\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0 \\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ hold? (I have tried to write out the matrix representation for A with respect to the decomposition $H=\overline{R(A^*)}\oplus null(A)$ but my  result doesn't coincide with the author's.) And why does $A_1$ have dense range?

How do we conclude that $B_{12}=B_{22}=0$ from the equation $B_{12}^*B_{12}+B_{22}^*B_{22}=0$?


According to me the decomposition of $A$ is wrong. The second column is $0$ as $A$ vanishes on $\ker A.$ But $\overline{R(A^)}$ is not necessarily invariant under the action of $A.$ It is invariant if $A$ is normal. Hence the lower left corner of the matrix may not vanish. For example consider $2\times 2$ matrices $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\ 1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad A^=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ The range of $A^*$ is not invariant under the action of $A.$

It suffices to use $A^*A=A^*B$ and $B^*A=B^*B.$ We obtain $A^*(A-B)=0$ and $B^*(A-B)=0.$ Subtracting these identities gives $(A-B)^*(A-B)=0.$ Thus $A-B=0.$
